# No styling or br element applied. Why its getting aligned vertically

Tags: html, css

I have following html without any styles applied.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>Image1 Description</h2>
        <img src="\images\Image1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Image2 Description</h2>
        <img src="\images\Image2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Image3 Description</h2>
        <img src="\images\Image3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Image4 Description</h2>
        <img src="\images\Image4.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run this (http://jsfiddle.net/zQKVu/), it shows me h2 text then its images vertically even though I haven't added any line break `<br/>` element and I am just wondering why these elements are getting aligned vertically and not horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `div` is not an inline element,it's a block same as `H2` element.

to display in same line :

use css property: `diplay:inline;`

Answer (score 3):

That's the nature of header tags, they default to `display: block`. You can change it with

```
h2 { 
  display: inline; 
}
```

See the forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c3UCs/

Comment: Just for advice to OP, it's probably not best to blanket rule this for `h2` tags, but define it where and when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

The default style for `<h2>` includes `display: block;`.

Answer (score 0):

header are block elements so they take all of the space availble clearing all other elements.

To display the pictures inline with the headers use:

```
h2{
    display:inline;
}
```